# How to make my 2D character stand normally on slope?

Tags: 2d, physics, unity, rotation, procedural

I've got this character in Unity3D (2D Mode)...
in a a slope which looks like this,
[image]

But I want the character to stand along the red line..Like below
[image]

How can I make it in Unity3d?

I've got this setup..

[image]

I'm using simple Addforce for movement...
If I remove the z position constraint it results in weird movement like rolling and so on....
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you considered that it looks very odd for a person to standing perpendicular to a slope?

[image: standing perpendicular to a slope]

You need to be upright to stay in balance.

---

Some alternatives:

- Treat his feet as a separate object and rotate them to be parallel to the slope. (A raycast will find the angle's [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)), as [dnk described](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/107831/7804). The angle for the feet is *that + 90°*.)

  [image: rotated feet]
- Fake it, by moving the whole character a little downwards.

  [image: faked "rotated" feet]

Comment: thank you all :)
I made this after your suggestion
http://i.imgur.com/io3v7Y4.png

Comment: That also suggests that as soon as the rotated feet do not look nicely any more, your character should stumble :)

Comment: :-/ Does the rotation of the feet look odd in the picture I attached?

Comment: @jamius19 They look good to me. I think Hagen's comment was a joke.

Comment: You don't need to move the character downwards just move the visual of the slope upwards a bit relative to the physical

Answer (score 2):

Try using RaycastHit.normal on ground to get normal. Them put char.up = normal

Comment: Why waste CPU with a raycast if the Unity physics already gives this information by default on every collision?